# The rule $\phi \leadsto \phi\land\psi$ is not sound

Tags: logic

I have been asked to show that this rule is not sound: $$\frac{\varphi}{\varphi\wedge\psi}\wedge I'$$
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work in propositional logic with variable letters $A$ and $B$. Let $\phi = A \lor \lnot A$ and let $\psi = B$. Now $\phi$ is true in every valuation, but $\phi \land \psi$ is not true in every valuation. Therefore, the inference rule is not sound.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, just one thing I'm still not clear on. Why does $\phi = A \lor \lnot A$ ?

Comment: I picked it arbitrarily. The important thing is that $\phi$ is a tautology and $\psi$ is not.